# Become a travel agent just for yourself to get deals

Tags: travel-agents

Can I get better deals, free upgrades for myself if I become a travel agent?

What I mean is, will becoming a registered agent automatically grant me access to deals, upgrades, good deals on car rentals etc etc. or do I need to actually provide these hotels and airlines with some client business before asking for deals?

Comment: Yes...canada is the home country

Answer (score 5):

The short answer - Not really.  Good perks come with sales.

Travel agents qualify for discounts on a number of items, like flights, cruises, hotels.  But these discounts are usually applied to full fares or rack rates, so with the discount their cost is often the same as the discounted internet rate you and I get.  The only difference is with their discount deal, they aren't stuck with all the non-refundable, non-changeable restrictions we may get.

Once an agent starts producing, then the suppliers start providing them with real perks, free stuff, etc.  And the more you sell, the better the perks.

There are a lot of travel agent card mills that talk a good story about all the deals you get armed with your official Travel Agent ID, but in the long run it is not a good as the pitch.